# Stop event propagation for multiple inline functions JS

Tags: javascript, events, inline, stoppropagation

I have this type of code :

```
<button onclick="fn1();fn2();fn3()">Clic</button>
```

I test something in fn1 and if it is true, I don't want fn2 and fn3 to be called. I used event.stopPropagation() in fn1 (in a cross-browser manner and passing the event to the function) but the others functions are called anyway.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Why don't you just properly attach three event listeners instead of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function fn1() {
        alert('fn1()');
        return false;
    }

    function fn2() {
        alert('fn2()');
        return true;
    }

    function fn3() {
        alert('fn3()');
        window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="fn1()&&fn2()&&fn3()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

all functions should return boolean
then use logical operators && inside onclick

```
<button onclick="fn1()&&fn2()&&fn3()">Click</button>
```

as you can see if the fn1() returns false f2() and f3() are not executed.

Comment: Thanks. This works. The only bad point is that you need to habe a return true to fire the next fonction... But it's woring well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice but there is a way.  You can throw your own Exceptions just to stop the execution.  I say it again it's not a good practice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function one(){
    var a = 1;
    console.log('one');
    if(a == 1){
        throw new RangeError("Sorry, but you are too young for this movie");
    }
}
function two(){
    console.log('two');
}
</script>

<button onclick="one();two();">Click me.</button>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks but it's true that it's a little bit hard to fire an error ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can change your fn1 function to return the result of the check you perform. Then you can change the onclick attribute to:

```
if (!fn1()) { fn2(); fn3(); };
```

I also recommend getting acquainted with [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of using the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a if condition in the button similar to the one mentioned below:

```
<button onclick="if(!fn1()){fn2();fn3()}">Click</button>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhwgfzqd/)

Comment: In your JSFiddle, if you change the onclick by
   <button onclick="if(fn1()){fn2();fn3()}">Click</button>
The fn2 and fn3 are still not fired, even with the return true in fn1...

Comment: hi @Fred: the condition is if(!fn1()) and it is returning true in the fiddle so it will not executing fn2 and fn3 and if we change the return to false it will execute them as the requirement

Comment: @fred let me change the return and add the fiddle in this comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uhwgfzqd/1/

Comment: @Fred: this fiddle is with your button html markup which is going to fn2 and fn3 as it is true http://jsfiddle.net/uhwgfzqd/2/

Comment: Yes OK I did the changes... I probably made a mistake... OK :)

Comment: ^^ it could be. It's true that it doesn't need to have a return true in the 2nd function to work as I expect... but it's less comprehensible, I think. Can I accept 2 responses for a question ?

Comment: @Fred: You cannot, if you think this is not appropriate solution then you should not accept it...otherwise you can change the answer